# Display image without scaling to view

Tags: ios, swift

In following code, even small images enlarge and fill whole view.  Could you please help me how to display image as it's original state.

```
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    if let inputCIImage = inputCIImage {
        clampFilter.setValue(inputCIImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        blurFilter.setValue(clampFilter.outputImage!, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: drawableWidth, height: drawableHeight)
        ciContext.drawImage(blurFilter.outputImage!, inRect: rect, fromRect: inputCIImage.extent)        
    }
}
```

Comment: what do the variables drawableWidth and drawableHeight stand for?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out with following way :

```
func aspectFit(fromRect: CGRect, toRect: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    let fromAspectRatio = fromRect.size.width / fromRect.size.height;
    let toAspectRatio = toRect.size.width / toRect.size.height;

    var fitRect = toRect

    if (fromAspectRatio > toAspectRatio) {
        fitRect.size.height = toRect.size.width / fromAspectRatio;
        fitRect.origin.y += (toRect.size.height - fitRect.size.height) * 0.5;
    } else {
        fitRect.size.width = toRect.size.height  * fromAspectRatio;
        fitRect.origin.x += (toRect.size.width - fitRect.size.width) * 0.5;
    }

    return CGRectIntegral(fitRect)
}

func aspectFill(fromRect: CGRect, toRect: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    let fromAspectRatio = fromRect.size.width / fromRect.size.height;
    let toAspectRatio = toRect.size.width / toRect.size.height;

    var fitRect = toRect

    if (fromAspectRatio > toAspectRatio) {
        fitRect.size.width = toRect.size.height  * fromAspectRatio;
        fitRect.origin.x += (toRect.size.width - fitRect.size.width) * 0.5;
    } else {
        fitRect.size.height = toRect.size.width / fromAspectRatio;
        fitRect.origin.y += (toRect.size.height - fitRect.size.height) * 0.5;
    }

    return CGRectIntegral(fitRect)
}
func imageBoundsForContentMode(fromRect: CGRect, toRect: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    switch contentMode {
    case .ScaleAspectFill:
        return aspectFill(fromRect, toRect: toRect)
    case .ScaleAspectFit:
        return aspectFit(fromRect, toRect: toRect)
    default:
        return fromRect
    }
}

override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    if let inputCIImage = inputCIImage {
        clampFilter.setValue(inputCIImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        blurFilter.setValue(clampFilter.outputImage!, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: drawableWidth, height: drawableHeight)

        let inputBounds = inputCIImage.extent

        let targetBounds = imageBoundsForContentMode(inputBounds, toRect: rect)

        ciContext.drawImage(blurFilter.outputImage!, inRect: targetBounds, fromRect: inputCIImage.extent)




    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the size of image like if your image is

```
let image = UIImage(named: "someImage.png")
```

then you can get its width and size

```
print(image.size)
```

and then pass the size to your custom view to make the size you want.